# url rewrite on same page but different url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have followin url rewrite code.

`RewriteRule category/(.*).html game.php?subcatmain=$1`

`RewriteRule category/(.*)/(.*).html game.php?subcatmain=$2`

I want to get main category and subcategories data on game.php.
Rewrite rule 1 is working with this url `www.example.com/project/category/games/`
but rule 2 is not working. Rule 2 result should be as 
`www.example.com/project/category/games/racing-games`

I think it is due to the keyword "category" duplication. so how to avoid duplication?

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect regex.

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^.]+)\.html$ game.php?subcatmain=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ game.php?catmain=$1&subcatmain=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```